# How can I detect if a request is blocked by an AdBlocker?

Tags: vue.js, request, adblock

We have a page in Vue Js and we have noticed that some requests are blocked by Adblocker, I would like to detect when this happens (only when a request is blocked)

Comment: My first question is why has X adblock added an asset you need/are using to their block list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an endpoint which looks like an advert to fool adblock into blocking it, and load it in a script tag i.e:

```
<script src="/adverts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The endpoint then returns some basic js to create a dummy element on the page:

```
app.get('/adverts.js', function (req, res, next) {
    const response = `var a=document.createElement('div');a.id='advert-test';a.style.display='none';document.body.appendChild(a)`

    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript')
    res.setHeader('content-length', response.length)
    res.send(response)
})
```

Then on the page or in your app you can simply look for the element which should have been loaded, if it wasn't then it was blocked, which will indicate the user has adBlock enabled:

`let adBlocked = document.getElementById('advert-test') ? false : true`

If you're trying to work around adBlock blocking images, don't name your asset with ad characteristics like common image dimensions for ads. ie. `/ads/ad375x50.jpg` instead use something like `/a/708e8144b8c034c8bde17391ef1bf9c1.jpg` and match/map the hash with the actual file. This includes DOM ids and classes like `class="share"` will get hidden ([heres](https://gist.github.com/lcherone/55d982b6bd67421451dabde708d25522) a list of blocked classes).

If you're trying to work around loading AdSense or a 3rd party domain etc you're out of luck as there is no workaround for that.

Comment: It seems /adverts.js  is no more catched by AdBlocker, any ideas for new names?

Comment: Try changing it to `ads.js`

Comment: alternatively, find a default list used and make the url match one of the blocked paths/params https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt